# How to iterate over array of hashes, then populate new hash keys using iterated hash values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
result = [
  {:label=>:road, :value=>"carl-schurz str."},
  {:label=>:house_number, :value=>"25"},
  {:label=>:postcode, :value=>"36041"},
  {:label=>:city, :value=>"fulda"},
  {:label=>:state_district, :value=>"fulda kreis"}
]
```

I would like to return a hash like the following:

```
output = {
  "road" => "carl-schurz str.",
  "house_number" => "25",
  "postcode" => "36041",
  "city" => "fulda",
  "state_district" => "fulda kreis"
}
```

Since I know that hashes can also have positions, I've been trying things like:

```
result.each do |r|
    r.each do |key, value|
      output[value[0]] = value[1]
    end
   end
```

But I'm not getting the correct results..

Comment: "I'm not getting the correct results" is not really very precise. What results do you get? In what way are they not correct?

Comment: By the way, there are tens of thousands of questions on [so] about "how do I transform this nested array of hashes of hashes of arrays of hashes of strings to arrays of hashes of arrays of integers into this other nested hash of hashes of arrays of symbols" or something similar, and the answer is *always* the same: Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an array-arrays-of-hashes-from-symbols-to-arrays-of-strings-oriented language. Re-design your data model so that you don't *have* those complex structures in the first place, and then you don't need to transform them.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding some other solutions FYI.

I personally would have done something like this:

```
Hash[result.map { |h| [h[:label], h[:value]] }]
```

Another thing you could look into is [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object), which can be pretty handy for constructing new objects. In this case that would look something like:

```
new_hash = result.each_with_object({}) do |h, r|
  r[h[:label]] = h[:value]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, other ways to accomplish it are always appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily with "map"...

```
result.map { |h| [h[:label], h[:value]] }.to_h
Hash[result.map { |h| [h[:label], h[:value]] }]
```

...or even "reduce"...

```
result.reduce(Hash.new) { |h,o| h[o[:label]] = o[:value]; h }
```

This simple benchmark shows that the "reduce" form is slightly faster than the others:

```
require 'benchmark'

result = [
  {:label=>:road, :value=>"carl-schurz str."},
  {:label=>:house_number, :value=>"25"},
  {:label=>:postcode, :value=>"36041"},
  {:label=>:city, :value=>"fulda"},
  {:label=>:state_district, :value=>"fulda kreis"}
] 

n = 1_000_000

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('Hash[]    ') { n.times { Hash[result.map { |h| [h[:label], h[:value]] }] } }
  x.report('map...to_h') { n.times { result.map { |h| [h[:label], h[:value]] }.to_h } }
  x.report('reduce    ') { n.times { result.reduce(Hash.new) { |h,o| h[o[:label]] = o[:value]; h } } }
end

#                  user     system      total        real
# Hash[]       1.830000   0.040000   1.870000 (  1.882664)
# map...to_h   1.760000   0.040000   1.800000 (  1.810998)
# reduce       1.590000   0.030000   1.620000 (  1.633808) *
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result.map { |h| h.values_at(:label, :value) }.to_h
  #=> {:road=>"carl-schurz str.", :house_number=>"25", :postcode=>"36041", 
  #    :city=>"fulda", :state_district=>"fulda kreis"}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

```
result.map.with_object({}) { |h, new_h| new_h[h[:label]] = h[:value] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired result using this:

```
result.each do |r|
  output[r.values[0]] = values[1]
end
```

Knowing to use hash_object.values was the key.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo? `output[r.values[0]] = r.values[1]`